# UIImage loses quality when rotated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, uiimage

I am using this code to rotate UIImage.

```
CGFloat DegreesToRads(CGFloat degrees) {
   return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}

- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image forAngle: (double) angle {

    float radians=DegreesToRads(angle);
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, radians);

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-image.size.width/2, -image.size.height/2 , image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage );

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;

}
```

Works ok, but the quality of image is worse after rotation. What could be the cause?

Comment: is it worse even when rotated by 90/180/270 degrees? or only when its at angels that lie between those

Comment: For any of those degrees.

Comment: only thing i could think of its that the image is not aligned to the pixels on the screen when rotated, but if the quality is also worse when rotated at a right angle, then im not sure.

Comment: try UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, NO, 2.0)

Comment: You don't take into account the retina screen CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size; the size is in point, you need to double the width and the height to have the dimension on pixel for a retina screen.

Comment: Simone, please make it an answer. It helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, NO, 2.0)
```

from apple documentation:

```
void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
   CGSize size,
   BOOL opaque,
   CGFloat scale
);
```

**Parameters**

- **size** The size (measured in points) of the new bitmap context. This represents the size of the image returned by the UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext function. To get the size of the bitmap in pixels, you must multiply the width and height values by the value in the scale parameter.
- **opaque**
  A Boolean flag indicating whether the bitmap is opaque. If you know the bitmap is fully opaque, specify YES to ignore the alpha channel and optimize the bitmap’s storage. Specifying NO means that the bitmap must include an alpha channel to handle any partially transparent pixels.
- **scale**
  The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

bye :)